# which 10Gb switch has native CX4 copper ports?

Tags: networking, cisco, switch, juniper, 10gbethernet

networking experts please help with a recommendation for a 10Gb switch that has at least 3 native CX4 copper ports and preferably some 10GBASE-T.

rack mount only!

anything in CISCO? Juniper?

We have bad luck with Dell powerconnect? it only has M8024 - blade chasis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use an [HP Procurve 6400cl switch](http://h10144.www1.hp.com/products/switches/ProCurve_Switch_6400cl_Series/overview.htm) #J8433A for my 10Gb storage networks. It's a 1U rackmount switch.

That provides:

```
6 CX4 10-GbE ports (IEEE 802.3ak Type 10Gbase-CX4)
Duplex: full only
```

The switch can be found for $2500 on eBay and is usually $4000+ elsewhere.

Comment: hi, thanks fore the info, but i am tied to Dell, Cisco, Juniper now.

Comment: Then no. You don't have any other options outside of a blade chassis or a CX4->fiber media converter.

Comment: what options exist for SFP+ to CX4 copper conversion. I know of only amphenol hybrid cables for QFP to CX4

Comment: stupid me but what are these? Cisco Catalyst 6500 Series10 Gigabit Ethernet Modules http://www.cisco.com/en/US/solutions/collateral/ns340/ns517/ns224/ns668/net_business_benefit0900aecd805348f3.html               + Pluggable Optics for Catalyst 6500 10 Gigabit Ethernet Modules X2-10GB-CX41

Comment: I've given you the proper answer. The HP is the only commonly available standalone switch that accommodates 4+ ports of CX4 cabling. The link you just posted is for a Cisco 6500-series chassis (blade) switch.

Comment: hi, no offense intended. I am newbie to the networking world.

Comment: I understand, but it's how the industry is going. I see the ZFS in your name, so I'm assuming you're using this with a ZFS-based filer. Again, I've been good with the HP Procurve solution above. Otherwise, you'll need to change your HBA and go to SFP+.

Comment: hey, here's something: http://www.bladenetwork.net/RackSwitch-G8100.html looks like all native CX4....not sure about the cost?

Answer (score 1):

so, FYI, Dell doesn't actually manufacture switches. They're all rebadged/oem'ed from other vendors.

So, limiting to Cisco/Juniper and you probably want the smallest enclosure possible. Actually, I don't know Juniper well enough to make a suggestion, so here is my Cisco recommendation.

Cisco 4900M switch w/ at least three 10Gbase-CX4 adapters and an 8 port 10Gbase-T module.
In ciscospeak, it's a WS-C4900M w/ a WS-X4908-10G-RJ45 and three X2-10GB-CX4.

It's a 2U semi-modular chassis with eight X2 slots along the bottom and two module-slots. The WS-X4908-10G-RJ45 is an eight port 10Gbase-T plug in module. Obviously, you could expand up to more fibre or CX4 ports using the five remaining X2 sockets at the bottom and you can also purchase a second 10Gbase-T module if you wanted more 10Gbase-T ports.

Does this work?

Edited to add the following:

If price is a concern, this is Cisco switch unlikely to be practical. It's overkill for simply a "storage switch". It can, however, do a lot of things above and beyond your average Layer2 switch. For example, hardware IPv4/IPv6 routing, ACLs, QoS policing, etc. I don't know what you want this switch for, so, well, I can't comment on that. If you get a quote on what I described above, though, I'd be amused to hear how much it costs.

I don't understand some of your comments on a previously submitted answer. At first you insist on Cisco, Dell or Juniper; but, later, you made  comment a comment soliciting thoughts on a RackSwitch G8100. If you're considering other vendors and only need layer 2 switching, then I'd also suggest you check HP's ProCurve line and Force10 networks. For example, the Force10 S2410.